# Show or Hide JQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a number of drop down lists on a webpage and am trying to use JQuery UI Autocomplete  Comboboxes. The Comboboxes work, my problem comes when I want to show or hide one of them. I can't seem to work out how to do it...

If my drop down lists are hidden when the page loads, the ui comboboxes for them are not. Alternatively, if I generate the combobox on an event, I can't then work out how to hide it when it is no longer needed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GhW8t/1/

The above, produces the autocomplete comboboxs correctly implace of "lstClients" & "lstOptions". However, I don't want lstOptions to be visible when the page loads. I need to show the list based on a selection made is lstClients.

Basically, I want to know how to control the visibility of the comboboxes.

Thanks.

**Solution:** Ok I have sorted this. Simply wrapping the source list boxes in divs will let you show and hide that div and all the controls within it, including the autocomplete combobox. This took me far too long to work out...

Comment: @DazzledKid - It's worth posting your solution as an answer to your own question so that this question is cleared from the Unanswered section

Comment: yes, answer the question and check it as the solution